# How to get a scrollbar for content with a sticky header and footer using CSS Grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The following is obviously a rookie CSS grid question, but how can one create a fixed header and footer in CSS grid and then create a scrollable main content area that has dynamically generated `<section>` elements each holding a fixed number other content elements? I have a pen [here](https://codepen.io/veksi/pen/xJJqZz) which is a fork of a Medium post and a pen from [here](https://medium.com/@vdsabev/simplify-your-layout-with-this-one-weird-trick-hint-its-css-grid-b9a2971a5649).

The problem I'm trying to solve is a bit more complicated than the usual CSS grid posts I could find in Internet -- sufficiently so to someone with very little CSS experience.

The complication I experience is that each section in the main content area can hold elements between `0` and `4` (or some other `[min, max]` range). The idea I've been toying with is that each section is certain `em` units high and some predetermined space (in `em` units) space is either divided vertically between the number of elements in each section or each element has a fixed size in `em` units (probably better). The overall number of sections isn't limited, so hence a scroll bar for the main content area that goes over all the sections.

In the linked pen I try to do this in `Section 1`, but as can be seen, not with good results. The contents of the first section overflows over the container over to the next one. I might be able to fiddle this so that I'll just adjust "magic numbers" in CSS, but it'd be nice to have ideas how to make this a bit more dynamic.

The HTML looks like this

```
<body>
  <main class="grid">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="bar">bar</div>
  <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>  
  <div id="content">
<section>
  <header>
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <a href="#">show all</a>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li>Section 1, item 1.</li>
    <li>Section 1, item 2.</li>
    <li>Section 1, item 3.</li>
    <li>Section 1, item 4.</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section>
  <header>
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <a href="#">show all</a>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li>Section 1, item 1.</li>
    <li>Section 2, item 2.</li>
    <li>Section 3, item 3.</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="unroll">      
   <button>show all in all sections</button>
</section>    
<button id="toggle-sidebar"><</button>
<footer>
   <p>This is a footer</p>
<footer>
</main>
```

While trying to solve this has actually created another problem. In the original pen the sidebar can be toggled to flow over the main content area. Now fidding this what I have, it appears I'm not able to do that anymore and I'm not sure what's the problem -- nor how to solve it.

So, two related problems in grid layout:

1. How to scroll a main content area of some height when the area has some number of sections each having between 0 and 4 elements. The vertical size of the sections can be fixed and the size of individual elements can be fixed.
2. When I resize the pen window, there's a "white leak" from the left side. It has something to have the general toggling problem.
3. How to bring back the toggle menu? Or put otherwise, what's the problem I fail to see here? :)

Comment: With grid or flex, you can set your layout with an height of 100vh, 3 containers on top of each others and add overflow on the main content. header and footer will not move. it will look like a frameset. grid or flex can be imbricated. you just need to know in how many pieces the layout is to be broken and how it should rearrange to be responsive the way you want it to be. basicly you are starting with 3 areas header,main,footer. inside each you'have other pieces and the same grid column can be applied to all of them via a class.

Comment: I fix some evening snack to kids and put them to bed and see if this moves me forward. Cheers!

Comment: yes best is to take a break to clear and ressource yourself ;)

Comment: Apparently they were silly mistakes and might've helped to take a break, though good some push helped with this and maybe something more broadly useful was produced. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I'm not leaving anything out here.

### Scroll content area:

Just add

```
height:200px; /*whatever height fits you*/
overflow-y:auto;
```

`overflow-y` controls the vertical scrollbar.

### white leak

Though it doesn't happen for me in your Pen, on 2K screen, 
maybe add `width` to the main view
set it to `100vw` - vw stands for View Width.

### Where's my button?!

Well , it's hidden becouse you have used  `transform:scale(0);`
which basically set it to have no size :).

Here is the "fixed" version https://codepen.io/itamarshdev/pen/RBBgxY

If I have missed anything, comment and I'll do my best to reply :)

## UPDATE:

According to you comment:

pen: https://codepen.io/itamarshdev/pen/RBBZbd

#### Scrollable content - add:

```
#content {
   grid-area: content;
   height: auto;
   overflow-y: auto;
   max-height: 100vh;
}
```

#### section is overflowing!

Well your math was wrong:

```
#content section ul {
  min-height: 5em;
  max-height: 20em;
}
#content section ul li {
  min-height: 5em;
  max-height: 5em;
}

section ul li {
   list-style: none;   
   background-color:#ff00ff;
   margin:0.5em;
}
```

See. 5*4em = 20em.

But you have margin on 0.5em around each element.
this meand 6*0.5em (between the elements) + 1em (top and bottom)  = 4em

So 24em will do!

```
#content section ul {
   min-height: 5em;
   max-height: 24em;
}
```

pen:https://codepen.io/itamarshdev/pen/RBBgxY

#### Sidebar Toggling

Works on mobile view (not to the correct side though)

#### Footer

What is the expected behavior for the footer? to stay a footer? ;)
Here you go:
change

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  body{
    grid-template-areas: 'header header' 'content content' 'footer footer';
  }
 ...
```

to

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: 'header header' 'content content' 'footer footer';
  }
...
```

Also better add the footer to grid :)

Also for "normal view"

```
grid-template-areas: "header header" "sidebar content" 'footer footer';
```

And add

```
footer {
   grid-area: footer;
}
```

pen: https://codepen.io/itamarshdev/pen/RBBZbd

Comment: It's certainly interesting in your pen that each of the sections individually are scrollable (I'm thinking side-scrolling/swiping on mobile), but I was thinking one scrollbar for both of the sections and each section having the elements they have (and each of the sections could have a fixed height). If you resize the window smaller, the footer takes the space on the left side. Plus the button doesn't toggle the sidebar over the content area. But I'll give a whirl with these ideas once I've fixed the kids some evening snack and got them to bed. :)

Comment: time with the kids is the best. hope I have helped :)

Comment: That did the trick. Cheers for the pen, I'll continue doodling. That first one too should be interesting for mobile users, I believe!

Comment: Good luck! wish you a much time with the kids is possible :)