# Scrollbar to CSS grid cell with first strecthing it to vertically to available space

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

As a continuation to my previous question [How to get a scrollbar for content with a sticky header and footer using CSS Grid layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696891/how-to-get-a-scrollbar-for-content-with-a-sticky-header-and-footer-using-css-gri/51697164?noredirect=1#comment90357206_51697164) (phew, what a heading!), I'm trying to drill in the concept of fixing some element to have a scroll-bar while still maintaining sticky header and footer.

This matches quite closely the previous question, but it appears I haven't learned it well enough. I might be wrong, but it appears I have trouble understanding the `grid-template-columns: repeat` directives, since now I don't see to get a good grip of the content areas. I would like the whole *main content area* to fill in all the available space and have a scrollbar appear only when there's enough content to warrant doing so. In other words, I'd like to create (again) sticky headers and footers and a scrollable content area, but this time is different. :)

I have a pen [here](https://codepen.io/veksi/pen/LBgyrP), which is a fork of the code described in article [How to Build an Off-Canvas Navigation With CSS Grid](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-an-off-canvas-navigation-with-css-grid--cms-28191).

I have made only a slight modification to the forked code by adding

```
.container section {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: max-height;
}
```

which makes a scrollbar always appear the content area, even if the contents wouldn't fill the whole area. Another problems besides that is that scrollbar is visible all the time.

The problems:

1. How to make the scrollbar visible only when vertical space is exhausted in the content area?
2. How to make the content area fill "the rest" of the viewport and creating an effect where there's a sticky header and footer?

I read amongst others the article [CSS Grid Gotchas And Stumbling Blocks](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/09/css-grid-gotchas-stumbling-blocks/) by **Rachel Andrew** and gather that I (maybe) need to set some container to a fixed size, but I'm not sure about that since scrollbar does appear without that too (though that might precisely be the problem as now it's always visible). This CSS also looks more general (maybe more efficient too?) than the one linked first in the beginning, hence the desire to further explore this.

Anyhow, it looks like for the time being I've mentally exhausted myself. Hence asking help/guidande/pointers/just code to see this through. :)

<edit: I've modified the pen a bit so that now it sports

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container section {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And to show what I mean with that `section` element taking all space, or pushing the footer downwards to stay in the lower end of the screen, I see

%lt;edit: A quickie, the "odd gap" can be removed by adding `min-height: 100vh` to the container element, now it looks like

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;  
  grid-gap: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh
```

}

This feels *logical* since it by default (I'd need to check the spec for this) the elements occupy the least space they can fit. I'll check about that about "main" later, I think it suffices to set a maximum size for the footer and title, so there's no other choice for the main other than to fill in so as to not to leave empty space.

[image: The gap]

Comment: *re: Problem 1:* Don't use `overflow: scroll`. That renders the scroll track at all times. Use `overflow: auto`, that renders the scroll track only when necessary.

Comment: True! Let's see if I make progress to the other part today (just slept over night). :)